# Add series name inside stacked area chart

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to add series name inside a stacked area chart? Somehow I would like to add different series names inside their corresponding stacked areas. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)? Look at the [`dataLabels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.formatter):

```
            formatter: function () {
                return 'The value for <b>' + this.series.name +
                    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
            }
```

This looks pretty ungainly but it works.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/g07mmpch/). I am using dataLabels only on the 5th point in the data series. I have some other options enabled and am including a box to better show the label. YMMV.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            borderRadius: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#AAA',
            y: 75,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: "#606060",
                fontSize: "11px"
            },
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.point.index === 4) {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That is a good solution but setting the index will work if the chart is static. The chart I have has more than 5 series and the areas change frequently. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could put the label on the last point on the right and shift the label to the right of the point as well. You will have to play with your positioning and I can see several ways this could look bad. Is it a requirement?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes. it is a requirement. Basically, I am looking for a chart software that can do that can position the label in the the best spot.If the area is small, the label can be outside the area and has an arrow that points towards the area.